How to evaluate the KL divergence between two distributions that may require sampling?
The KL divergence between two distributions is:
\begin{equation}
   \int \mathbf{p}(x;\theta_{1}) \; log \frac{\mathbf{p}(x;\theta_{1})}{\mathbf{p}(x;\theta_{2})} \nu(dx) \\
\end{equation}
If the expression $\mathbf{p}(x;\theta)$ is specified by its canonical parameters, we can simply calculate the KL divergence using the expressions of $\mathbf{p}$. However in the case of (conditional: deleted) distributions (where random vector $\mathbf{x}$ appears: added) $\mathbf{p}(y|x;\theta_{1})$, how would one find the KL divergence? Would it require sampling many $x$'s to estimate this value?
As a concrete example, in the case of Logistic regression we have for some random initialized $\theta_0$:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{p}(y = 1|x;\theta_0) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta_0^{\intercal}x}} \quad\quad
    \mathbf{p}(y = 0|x;\theta_0) = \frac{e^{-\theta_0^{\intercal}x}}{1+e^{-\theta_0^{\intercal}x}}.
\end{equation}
and another one with $\theta_1$:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{p}(y = 1|x;\theta_1) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta_1^{\intercal}x}} \quad\quad
    \mathbf{p}(y = 0|x;\theta_1) = \frac{e^{-\theta_1^{\intercal}x}}{1+e^{-\theta_1^{\intercal}x}}.
\end{equation}
Now we want to compute the improvement of model $\theta_1$ over $\theta_0$, using KL divergence:
\begin{align*}
    D(P(y|x;\theta_0)|P(y|x;\theta_1)) &= \frac{1}{1+exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)} \cdot ln \biggl(
    \frac{1+exp(-\theta_{1}^{\intercal}x)}{1+exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)} \biggr) \\
    &+\;
    \frac{exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)}{1+exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)} \cdot ln \biggl(
    \frac{1+exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)}{exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal}x)} \cdot
    \frac{exp(-\theta_{1}^{\intercal}x)}{1+exp(-\theta_{1}^{\intercal}x)} \biggr).\\
\end{align*}
How would one evaluate $exp(-\theta_0^{\intercal} x)$? Would you sample the values of x if possible? Now suppose you have many examples of $x$ available, ie in a training set, would it be "fair" to sample from the training set to evaluate $D$?
edit
Removed the "conditional distribution", and replaced it with expressions where random vector $\mathbf{x}$ makes an appearance in the definition. There is a comparable question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016421/confused-by-kullback-leibler-on-conditional-probability-distributions. But in that case the accepted answer compute the expected value of the KL divergence wrt the distribution $P(x)$. But in my case I do not have this distribution $P(x)$, only a dataset $\{(x_1,y_1),..,(x_n,y_n)\}$. I can evaluate the quantitity $D(P(y|x;\theta_0)|P(y|x;\theta_1))$ for every $(x_i,y_i)$ in the dataset, but how would you compute the expecatation:
\begin{equation}
E_{x \sim P(x)}[ D(P(y|x;\theta_0)|P(y|x;\theta_1)) ] 
\end{equation}
without this $P(x)$?. The naive method is to assume $P(x)$ is a uniform distribution, at which point the expectation is just the average... but it seems like a better solutions is available somewhere. The closest I can find is this: https://www.tsc.uc3m.es/~fernando/bare_conf3.pdf, which builds a CMF from the data itself.

The distribution being conditional or not does not change the notion of KL divergence.
Indeed, given $p(x) \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $q(x) \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, the KL can be estimated in closed form.
However, the KL between $p(y|x) \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $q(y|x) \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ shares the same closed form with the previous one
The only thing you have to know is what family of distribution does the conditional probability falls in
And in your example, $x$ is the conditioning, thus you are saying that "you know a point estimate $\theta$ and a point estimate $x$", which means that that term can be estimated in closed form as it's a product of two point estimates, aka numbers/vectors

the solution of you (last) formulation is straightforward, as $P(y|x,\theta) ~ Bernoulli$, and the kl of discrete distribution is trivial
The only thing you have to do is to compute the KL sample wise, and then average the KL over all the samples
What you will get is a unbiased monte carlo estimate of your overall KL

Ah yeah that make sense. the question is a bit confused. So really I should ask given the distribution cannot be written in closed form, or if the random vector $\mathbf{x}$ makes an appearance in the distribution like above, how do you estimate the KL divergence? Would you sample out of some $P(\mathbf{x})$ to estimate it? It seems like this is the way: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0853 , https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280885/estimate-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence-with-monte-carlo.  Does it make sense to say "the KL divergence evaluated at some point $x$"?

@xiaolingxiao conditioning on X means that you already know X, so you would just proceed to use it as if it's a constant, and not a random variable... on the who would you estimate a KL of two non parametric distributions, you need to resort to approximations, and since KL is just an integral, if it's low dimensions you can use quadrature procedures, but if it's somewhat high dimension, something like monte carlo estimate (there are more advanced procedures, however at that point it highly depends on your specific problem)

if i have many X's, ie data = ${(x_1, y_1),..,(x_n, y_n)}$, then the KL divergence would be evaluated at every point $x_i$? But what exactly is this quantity $D(\theta_0||\theta_1) | x_i$, is it the KL divergence between two distributions at the point $x_i$?. And if you computed the set of values $ D(\theta_0||\theta_1) | x_1, ..,  D(\theta_0||\theta_1) | x_n$, then what do you do with the set? Do you just average them? what would be the principle behind the average? Moreover, how do you account for the fact the sample may be biased?

@xiaolingxiao well that's your problem definition, i can't tell you what that means... also, you are increasing the non-clear part, now you start by definition two distribution $y|x,\theta$ and then comparing instead the distribution of the $\theta$ where earlier they were just conditional informations, so the initial distributions seems useless now

@xiaolingxiao I would suggest you to open a new question where you stead the REAL problem, and not a paraphrasis of your, because for the moment, seems like you have a dataset XY, some parameters $\theta$, and you are trying to estimate the distance between two parameters distributions (which makes no sense for the current formalization)

I meant there's 2 distributions with 2 different $\theta$: $\theta_0$ - a random initialization, & $\theta_1$ - a better estimate. The point is to compute the "improvement"  in quality of $\theta_1$ over $\theta_0$. The idea is to evaluate this improvement on the dataset, so the expected KL divergence is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016421/confused-by-kullback-leibler-on-conditional-probability-distributions. But that def assumes there is $P(x)$, which I do not have. Averaging it would be assuming uniform distribution.

I edited the question so it's easier to read.

@xiaolingxiao it's still a bit unclear, because of the "some training" is not well defined. Initially $\theta_0$ is a point estimate (a specific vector say), and after training, it's also still a specific vector, just a different one. At no point in this whole procedure, $\theta$ represents a distribution, thus estimating the KL divergence, it's impossible (it's infinite for two point estimate/lambda distributions)

i changed the notation so it's more clear. $\theta$ is the parameter to a distribution, I'm trying to compute the divergence between two different distributions.

@xiaolingxiao sorry but I have to say it... do you realize how your change in notation completely changes the problem?

@xiaolingxiao answered on the answer, but please consider that wants to be the last answer, as it's probably the 3rd completely different formulation you are posting, and it's 100% against the community rules

why is this true: "What you will get is a unbiased monte carlo estimate of your overall KL"? As in why is it that the sample KL divergence is the unbiased estimate? It's only true in so far as the sample it self is unbiased right?

@xiaolingxiao it's an unbiased estimate for the distribution you have in your hand, that's it. you have a coin that gives you 80% times head and is bised? the MC estimate will tell you that the coin gives head 80% of the times (aka an unbiased estimate)
